# MongoDB query performance depending on index types

Tags: mongodb, query-performance

Probably this question has been asked before or is something really straightforward that wouldn't need to be asked but I'm quite intrigued as I've seen some examples where indexes are built with a hashed field that comes from another application which basically comes from another value in the Document, instead of using the raw String value instead.

So my question basically is, does MongoDB query documents faster with...

`(name: String, age: Int64)` this index or...

`(hash_name: Int64, age: Int64)` this one?

Do types have an impact on performance?

Answer (score 0):

Building index on combination of different data types doesn't impact performance. But the order in which you build the index and your access patterns will have impact. Make sure you build your indexes in Equality, Sort and Range (ESR) order and build your query accordingly